# How to init my component every time I change router back?

Tags: javascript, components, vue.js, vue-resource, vue-router

I have a component for add a user with a form,after I submit the form,leaving it and get back,I find the data I wrote last time is still there.

So,how to reset(re-init) the component every time I leave it?

Answer (score 1):

do you have the `keep-alive` option enabled?

```
<router-view keep-alive></router-view>
```

This would explain the behaviour. If that'S not the issue, you can set `canReuse: false` in the components `route:` options:

```
export default {
  // ...
  route: {
    canReuse: false
  }
}
```